# Discuss the convergence of these improper integrals in terms of $\alpha>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

The integrals are the following ones:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(\log x)^{\alpha}}{x^{2/3}\arctan(1/x)}dx$$
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{(x^{2}-1)^{\alpha}}dx$$

I would like to know if my arguments are correct or not: I would appreciate any advice. Thanks in advice!

These are my attempts:

*Note: When I write $\sim$, I am saying "which has the same character as" or, if you want, I am using a comparison criteria.*

Choosing $k
>0$ big enough,
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(\log x)^{\alpha}}{x^{2/3}\arctan(1/x)}dx\sim\int_{k}^{\infty}\frac{(\log x)^{\alpha}}{x^{2/3}\arctan(1/x)}dx.$$
Then, $\arctan(1/x)\sim 1/x$, and so,
$$\int_{k}^{\infty}\frac{(\log x)^{\alpha}}{x^{2/3}\arctan(1/x)}dx\sim\int_{k}^{\infty}x^{1/3}(\log x)^{\alpha}dx.$$
At this point, also, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $\log x\leq Cx$. Thus,
$$\int_{k}^{\infty}x^{1/3}(\log x)^{\alpha}dx\leq\int_{k}^{\infty}x^{1/3}(Cx)^{\alpha}dx=\int_{k}^{\infty}C^{\alpha}x^{1/3+\alpha}dx\sim\int_{k}^{\infty}x^{1/3+\alpha}dx=\int_{k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{-1/3-\alpha}}dx.$$
This last integral is convergent if and only if $-1/3-\alpha>1$, which is not possible since $\alpha>0$.

Hence, the first integral is always divergent.

In order to study the second integral, we must notice that $x=1$ is a problematic point (we divide by $0$), so it is convenient to choose $\varepsilon>0$ and write that
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{(x^{2}-1)^{\alpha}}dx=\int_{1}^{1+\varepsilon}\frac{\sin x}{(x^{2}-1)^{\alpha}}dx+\int_{1+\varepsilon}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{(x^{2}-1)^{\alpha}}dx.$$

I will call $(1)$ and $(2)$ each of the previous terms from now on.

In $(1)$, $\sin x\sim x$ and $x^{2}$ is negligible. In consequence,
$$\int_{1}^{1+\varepsilon}\frac{\sin x}{(x^{2}-1)^{\alpha}}\sim\int_{1}^{1+\varepsilon}\frac{x}{(-1)^{\alpha}}dx,$$
which is clearly convergent no matter what value $\alpha$ has (we could calculate the integral explicitely and obtain a finite result).

In $(2)$, we can choose $k'>0$ big enough and say that
$$\int_{1+\varepsilon}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{(x^{2}-1)^{\alpha}}dx\sim\int_{k'}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{2\alpha}}dx\leq\int_{k'}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2\alpha}}dx,$$
which is convergent if and only if $2\alpha>1$, which is the same as saying $\alpha>1/2$.

Hence, the second integral is convergent if and only if $\alpha>1/2$.

Comment: The justification for the first integral is not right. When you used $\log x\le Cx$ you obtained that your integral is **less** than a divergent integral. But that's not helpful. I have for example $e^{-x}\lt 1/x$. Then $\int_1^\infty x^{-1}dx$ is divergent, but I can't conclude that $\int_1^\infty e^{-x}dx$ is divergent, since that is false.

Comment: You are right, thanks.

Comment: Then how could I proceed?

Comment: Just use $\log x>1$ for $x>e$. So then your integral is greater than $\int_e^\infty x^{1/3} dx$, which is divergent